# bootstrap thumbnails not stacking properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My thumbnails from bootstrap have different heights to them, and I think that issue might be causing them to not stack properly (see screenshots and fiddle). I think I need to include a min-height for them, but I'm just not able to get it working .. can anyone lend a hand?

Here is the code that I have:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="hidden-phone">
        <a href="newBook.php">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="float:right; margin-top:30px;" type="button">Add Book</button>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 well">

        <div class="row-fluid">
          <ul class="thumbnails">

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>

                  <p>Seller: Me</p>
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <p>Cost: </p>
                  <p>Condition: </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                  <span class="label label-warning" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Book has been sold!</span>
                  <p>Seller: Me</p>
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <p>Cost: </p>
                  <p>Condition: </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>

                  <p>Seller: Me</p>
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <p>Cost: </p>
                  <p>Condition: </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 

             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>

                  <p>Seller: Me</p>
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <p>Cost: </p>
                  <p>Condition: </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
                         <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>

                  <p>Seller: Me</p>
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <p>Cost: </p>
                  <p>Condition: </p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 

          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VwZ/`

screens:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, height of divs is not the issue. Issue is that you must put only three divs with `.span4` class in one div with `.row-fluid` class. And if you want more divs with `.span4` you must create new div with `.row-fluid` class and put those new `.span4` divs inside. [See Twitter bootstrap official documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

For example, this is valid Twitter Bootstrap markup

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4"></div>
   <div class="span4"></div>
   <div class="span4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4"></div>
   <div class="span4"></div>
   <div class="span4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12"></div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span8"></div>
   <div class="span1"></div>
   <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

Here is working demo with your code >>> http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VwZ/1/

Comment: Well that certainly would do it .. I am running the internal divs (or li) through a loop from the DB, so I just need a way to figure out how print out the parent div (row-fluid) after 3 columns..

Comment: Well, this is an answer on your question from above :) You can accept this answer and ask another question about programming issue with description of problem and PHP code.

Comment: good point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869534/nested-for-loop-difficulties