# nested for loop difficulties

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

I need to print out a div that encapsulates three li's in them as I run through a list in a DB. As I am using bootstrap, I need to div with a .row-fluid for every row after the third column of .span4, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting the for loop working.. here is the untouched code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">'
          <ul class="thumbnails">
            <?php 
              for($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i+=1){ 
            ?>
            <!-- This is why sort by programme doesn't work - ID is not what I need -->
            <li class="span4" id="<?php echo $rows[$i]['Class']; ?>">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3><?php echo $rows[$i]['Title']; ?></h3>
                  <?php if(!empty($rows[$i]["DateSold"])){ ?>
                    <span class="label label-warning" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Book has been sold!</span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <p>Seller: <?php echo $rows[$i]['FirstName'] . " " . $rows[$i]['LastName']; ?> </p>
                  <p>Email: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Email']; ?></p>
                  <p>Cost: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Cost']; ?></p>
                  <p>Condition: <?php echo $rows[$i]['BookCondition']; ?></p>
                  <p align="center">
                    <?php echo '<a href="#myModal' . $i . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View More information</a>' ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
            <!-- Modal -->
              <?php echo'<div id="myModal' . $i . '" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'; ?>
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Book information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Title: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Title']; ?> </p>
                  <p>Seller: <?php echo $rows[$i]['FirstName'] . " " . $rows[$i]['LastName']; ?> </p>
                  <p>Email: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Email']; ?></p>
                  <p>Phone: <?php echo $rows[$i]['PhoneNumber']; ?></p>
                  <p>Condition: <?php echo $rows[$i]['BookCondition']; ?></p>
                  <p>Date added: <?php echo $rows[$i]['DateAdded']; ?></p>
                  <p>Class: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Class']; ?></p>
                  <p>Cost: <?php echo $rows[$i]['Cost']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php
            }
          ?>   
          </ul>
    </div>
```

I need that top parent div of row-fluid surrounding the list item after every third print from the DB..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second readthrough, it seems more like you want every three LIs in a seperate DIV and UL. In that case, you can use `array_chunk`.

```
<?php $chunks = array_chunk($rows, 3);
for ($i = 0; $i<count($chunks); $i++)
{
    ?> <div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails"> <?php
    for ($j = 0; $j<count($chunks[$i]); $j++)
    {
        ?> do your LIs in here <?php
    }
    ?> </ul></div> <?php
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about something like that, but how do you make sure that only three list items print out before the new row needs to start?

Comment: Use array_chunk. I rewrote my answer, because I think I misunderstood the question the first time.

Comment: I'm just reading through it now thanks (not heard of that function before so I'm going to try it)

Comment: Yeah that kind of worked - except for the li's it only printed out the first entry 3 times

Comment: think my variables are just switched actually

Comment: Instead of typing $rows[$i], you need to type $chunks[$i][$j], because it's a multidimensional array.