# Keeping thumbnails aligned in Twitter Bootstrap using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, thumbnails, angularjs-ng-repeat

As can be seen from the various questions on stackoverflow, Twitter Bootstrap doesn't properly align thumbnails.

How I solve this previously in Python, was similar to this [PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869534/nested-for-loop-difficulties); using a counter to detect row ending then create new `div` for it to go in.

What is the 'Angular'-way of doing this? - I'm guessing hacking together a solution with `span`s isn't the answer...

Here is a plnkr with a partial test-case; in my actual app the columns on the left aren't aligned either: http://plnkr.co/edit/u8FjvAvIFGLu7vq4KaLE

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what you're attempting to accomplish. What do you mean by "properly align thumbnails"?

Comment: Aligned vertically and horizontally; over any number of fluid rows and fluid columns.

Comment: So specifically with regards to your plnkr, the "Madam" thumbnail for example? How it is not aligned with the other thumbnails on its line?

Comment: In my example I was only able to replicate "Prof" not working. Drag the divider along a little bit to see it being out of alignment.

Comment: View the full size of the screen is defined as span12 resolution independent. You are setting up thumbs as span3 then 4x3 = 12. What comes after that is "broken" in the case, the fifth thumb.

Comment: Okay, so what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your sizing of the divs (span3) is messing with the position of the thumbnails. If you have your screen a certain width, for example, the text "we welcome you" spills over to the next line causing the thumbnail to be pushed down. This can be fixed by altering the sizing of your spans if necessary or possibly other methods such as playing around with how you've laid your html out. (possibly sticking the "we welcome you" on the next line). Also, as PiLHA mentioned in the comments, you need to be careful with how you use the bootstrap `span` classes.